# max n * n Reshape 2d numpy array function that discards lowest values and returns sum of col means?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, memory-management

I am working on this problem for my data science class:
Write a function that takes in an integer, and does the following:
Creates an array of the numbers from 0 up to that inputted integer
Reshapes it to be the largest n * n array that it could be, discarding any elements that are extra (i.e. if you want to make a 10 x 10, but have 102 elements, discard the last 2)
Returns the cumulative sum of the column means

I have the following code so far for the matrix reshaping, but it times out for large numbers. Any suggestions on how to complete the first step of this problem would be much appreciated.

```
    import numpy as np
def ranged_arr(n):
    ranged_arr = np.arange(0,n+1,1)
    if len(ranged_arr)%int(len(ranged_arr)**0.5)== 0:
        array = ranged_arr.reshape(int(len(ranged_arr)**0.5),int(len(ranged_arr)**0.5))
        return array
    else:
        len(ranged_arr)%int(len(ranged_arr)**0.5)!= 0
        idx = 0
        new_arr = np.arange(0,n-idx,1)
        while len(new_arr)%int(len(new_arr)**0.5)!= 0:
            idx +=1
        q = new_arr.reshape(int(len(new_arr)**0.5),int(len(new_arr)**0.5))
        return q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keep it sweet and simple :)

First, let's decompose your problem, you have to:

*1. Create an array of the numbers from 0 up to that inputted integer*

*2. Reshape it to be the largest m x m array that it could be*

*2.1. Find the largest dimension (m)*

Now let's write that Python function!

```
def ranged_arr(n):
    #Creates an array of the numbers from 0 up to that inputted integer 
    ranged_arr = np.arange(0,n+1)

    #Reshapes it to be the largest n * n array that it could be

    #Find the largest dim
    largest_dim = math.floor(math.sqrt(n+1))
    #Find the size of the array that will be reshaped
    last_index = largest_dim**2
    #Take the slice of the original array that could be reshaped
    fitted_ranged_arr = ranged_arr[:last_index]
    #Finally, reshape it!
    reshaped_range_arr = fitted_ranged_arr.reshape((largest_dim,largest_dim))

    #Return everything, so you can check the steps
    return ranged_arr,largest_dim,fitted_ranged_arr,reshaped_range_arr
```

I uploaded it to my Github so you can check it with some tests [here](https://github.com/alberduris/stackoverflow/blob/master/ranged_array_whd/RangedArray.ipynb)

Comment: Thank you very much, this really simplified the problem!

Answer (score 1):

From the code that @Alber8295 started, the rest of the problem:

```
def ranged_arr(n):
    #Creates an array of the numbers from 0 up to that inputted integer 
    ranged_arr = np.arange(0,n+1)

    #Reshapes it to be the largest n * n array that it could be

    #Find the largest dim
    largest_dim = math.floor(math.sqrt(n+1))
    #Find the size of the array that will be reshaped
    last_index = largest_dim**2
    #Take the slice of the original array that could be reshaped
    fitted_ranged_arr = ranged_arr[:last_index]
    #Finally, reshape it!
    reshaped_range_arr = fitted_ranged_arr.reshape((largest_dim,largest_dim))

    # get the sum of the col means 

    #get the means of each col
    col_means = np.mean(reshaped_range_arr,axis=0)
    # get the sum of the means 
    sum_of_means = col_means.sum()
    #Return everything, so you can check the steps
    return ranged_arr,largest_dim,fitted_ranged_arr,reshaped_range_arr,col_means, sum_of_means

    print(sum_of_means)
```

Comment: Glad to see you perfectly solved the rest of the exercise ^^